# IPN + Take customers to the URL when they finish checkout

Tags: paypal

I have configured an URL for IPN in the **general configuration** of my Paypal account.

Will this override the option called "Take customers to the URL when they finish checkout" (in the configuration of my button) ? (see below)
Or will both pages be called when succesful payment ? (IPN + "Take customers to the URL when they finish checkout")

[image: Button configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPN settings will not affect the auto return setting ("Take customers to the URL when they finish checkout"). The former is a HTTP callback for backend processing and the latter controls browser behavior for buyers.